# Render viewport material looks better than rendered

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, 3d-view

So I'm going for this stylized anime kind of look.

The problem is I prefer how it looks in the viewport not the rendered image version. The Material looks different. Im using cycles and dont want to use Evee because Im using a bevel node as part of the materials. Notice how the black outlines are less pronounced.

How do I get the materials to look like it does in the viewport?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, how did you do the grey background? Maybe show some screenshots or even share your file (remove the useless objects)

Comment: The grey background is easy. Just a Background node. If you go to materials then world it should be there.

Comment: that's weird, is the Color Management standard?

Comment: Could you please remove useless object (leave a cube instead of the plane) and share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: I am failing to reproduce your results with Blender 3.6.8 starting from a fresh file and a single cube, even limiting in Render panel *Max samples* to 68 as shown in your screen capture. Shading Editor view and Render window look pretty much the same. Here is my [Blender file](https://blend-exchange.com/b/QSGEOEOQ/). Could you share yours ?